# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker Months View Only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app and trying to use [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for my "month/year" field like the one in demo here:
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#min-view-mode

In that demo, it only allows users to select "year" and "month". Not "days". I want the same functionality in my app. However, in my app, it works the same on first click but on succeeding clicks it shows the "days" selection view. Setting the viewMode to 'years' doesn't fix the problem.

My model is as follows:

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public DateTime? StartMonthYear { get; set; }
    ...
```

My view is as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartMonthYear, new { @class = "month-picker" })
    ...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.month-picker').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'months',
            format: 'MM/YYYY',
            useCurrent: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around which works pretty well:

```
$(function () {
    $('.month-picker').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'months',
        format: 'MM/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false
    });

    $('.month-picker').on("dp.show", function (e) {
        $(e.target).data("DateTimePicker").viewMode("months");
    })
});
```

This is based on a reply found [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1894).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `viewMode` only sets the initial view. However, it seems this particular library doesn't provide any way to actually restrict which views are available.

There's an [alternate libary](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) that I personally use, which does give you the ability. It's virtually a drop-in replacement, so you shouldn't have to change much to switch over. However, importantly, it provides `minView`/`maxView` options you can utilize:

```
$(function () {
    $('.month-picker').datetimepicker({
        startView: 'month',
        minView: 'month',
        format: 'mm/yyyy'
    });
});
```

As you can see there's a few minor differences:

1. `viewMode` becomes `startView`. The view names are also singular `month` vs. `months`.
2. The formatting string is more similar to C# formatting, so you'd use lowercase `mm` and `yyyy`.
3. The default for this library is to use the current date/time, so there's no need for a separate `useCurrent` option. If you want to specify a different start date/time, you'd use `initialDate`.

Comment: In their demo (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#min-view-mode) it works not only on initial view but on succeeding as well. Thanks for suggesting alternative library. I might try that if all else fails.

Comment: The current library was chosen because it has this slick time picker which I also use in other DateTime fields in the app. So I'm kind of hesitant about the alternative datepicker you're suggesting.

Comment: To each his own, I guess. I actually far prefer the time picker of the other library.

Comment: Taking a closer look at your library, they do call out an example of using `Min View Mode`, but the code for that is virtually no different than just using `viewMode` normally. It seems dependent on the value for `format`, and if parts aren't included in the format string, those parts aren't available. However, that seems a little too magical for my tastes, and it's possible you're simply running into a bug in the logic. I'd contact the developer and/or create an issue on the github project.

Comment: I'll try contacting developer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the library and solved. I faced same problem and solved by simply downloading latest version.